# Wordpress Playlist WPSE

Tags: playlist

I using the plugin from https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist so far I really enjoy it, but I hope anyone can help me to change the code little bit, Like:
The original code:

```
[_playlist]
   [_track title="Ain't Misbehavin'" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3"]
   [_track title="Buddy Bolden's Blues" src="//s.w.org/images/core/3.9/JellyRollMorton-BuddyBoldensBlues.mp3"]
[/_playlist]
```

I want to change it to:

```
[_playlist]
   http://s.w.org/images/core/3.9/AintMisbehavin.mp3
   http://s.w.org/images/core/3.9/JellyRollMorton-BuddyBoldensBlues.mp3
[/_playlist]
```

Comment: That does mean you can't specify metadata on the tracks, like the title here or type=video/audio. (I guess it would be possible to fetch the URL, read embedded metadata from the file and cache that somewhere in the database?)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by changing the shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance you just need to change [get_tracks_from_content](https://github.com/birgire/wpse-playlist/blob/0.0.9/php/class.playlist.php#L153). Rather than running $content through do_shortcodes,

- split it by linebreaks (or whitespace?) and discard empty lines, or anything that isn't an URL

  - probably make the strip_tags call at this point, on each value you have left
- pass the URLs into track_shortcode as `[ "src" => $url ]`, plus any other common metadata you want to set here
- concatenate the results to make a new $content
- continue with the `// Replace last comma` code.

Answer (score 0):

I try out but had noluck, maybe I misunderstanding somewhere.
Here is the WPSE function file, Please show me where I need to edit:

```
<?php

namespace birgire;

/**
 * Class Playlist
 */

class Playlist
{
    protected $type     = '';
    protected $types    = array( 'audio', 'video' );
    protected $instance = 0;

    /**
     * Init - Register shortcodes
     */

    public function init()
    {
        add_shortcode( '_playlist',     array( $this, 'playlist_shortcode'  ) );
        add_shortcode( '_track',        array( $this, 'track_shortcode'     ) );

        // Deprecated:
        add_shortcode( 'wpse_playlist', array( $this, 'playlist_shortcode'  ) );
        add_shortcode( 'wpse_trac',     array( $this, 'track_shortcode'     ) );
    }


    /**
     * Callback for the [_playlist] shortcode
     *
     * @uses wp_validate_boolean() from WordPress 4.0
     */

    public function playlist_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) 
    {        
        global $content_width;  // Theme dependent content width
        $this->instance++;      // Counter to activate the 'wp_playlist_scripts' action only once

        $atts = shortcode_atts( 
            array(
                'type'           => 'audio',
                'style'          => 'light',
                'tracklist'      => 'true',
                'tracknumbers'   => 'true',
                'images'         => 'true',     // Audio related
                'artists'        => 'true',     // Audio related
                'current'        => 'true',
        'autoplay'       => 'false',
        'class'          => 'wpse-playlist',
        'width'          => '',
        'height'         => '',
        'outer'          => '20',
        'default_width'  => '640',
        'default_height' => '380',
            ), 
            $atts, 
            'wpse_playlist_shortcode' 
        );

        // Autoplay:
        $autoplay = wp_validate_boolean( $atts['autoplay'] ) ? 'autoplay="yes"' : '';

        // Nested shortcode support:
        $this->type = ( in_array( $atts['type'], $this->types, TRUE ) ) ? esc_attr( $atts['type'] ) : 'audio';

        // Enqueue default scripts and styles for the playlist.
        ( 1 === $this->instance ) && do_action( 'wp_playlist_scripts', esc_attr( $atts['type'] ), esc_attr( $atts['style'] ) );

        //----------
        // Height & Width - Adjusted from the WordPress core
        //----------

        $width = esc_attr( $atts['width'] );       
        if( empty( $width ) )
            $width = empty( $content_width ) 
                ? intval( $atts['default_width'] ) 
                : ( $content_width - intval( $atts['outer'] ) );

        $height = esc_attr( $atts['height'] );       
        if( empty( $height ) && intval( $atts['default_height'] ) > 0 )
            $height = empty( $content_width ) 
                ? intval( $atts['default_height'] )
                : round( ( intval( $atts['default_height'] ) * $width ) / intval( $atts['default_width'] ) );

        //----------
        // Output
        //----------

        $html = '';

        // Start div container:
        $html .= sprintf( '<div class="wp-playlist wp-%s-playlist wp-playlist-%s ' .  esc_attr( $atts['class'] ) . '">', 
        $this->type, 
            esc_attr( $atts['style'] )
        );

        // Current audio item:
        if( $atts['current'] && 'audio' === $this->type )
    {
            $html .= '<div class="wp-playlist-current-item"></div>';   
        }

        // Video player:                      
        if( 'video' === $this->type )
        {
            $html .= sprintf( '<video controls="controls" ' . $autoplay . ' preload="none" width="%s" height="%s"></video>',
                $width,
                $height
            );
        }
        // Audio player:                      
        else
        {
            $html .= sprintf( '<audio controls="controls" ' . $autoplay . ' preload="none" width="%s" style="visibility: hidden"></audio>', 
                $width 
            );
        }

        // Next/Previous:
        $html .= '<div class="wp-playlist-next"></div><div class="wp-playlist-prev"></div>';

        // JSON 
        $html .= sprintf( '
            <script class="wp-playlist-script" type="application/json">{
                "type":"%s",
                "tracklist":%s,
                "tracknumbers":%s,
                "images":%s,
                "artists":%s,
                "tracks":[%s]
            }</script>', 
            esc_attr( $atts['type'] ), 
            wp_validate_boolean( $atts['tracklist'] ) ? 'true' : 'false', 
            wp_validate_boolean( $atts['tracknumbers'] ) ? 'true' : 'false',  
            wp_validate_boolean( $atts['images'] ) ? 'true' : 'false',
            wp_validate_boolean( $atts['artists'] ) ? 'true' : 'false',
            $this->get_tracks_from_content( $content )
        );

        // Close div container:
        $html .= '</div>';

        return $html;
    }


    /**
     * Get tracks from the [_playlist] shortcode content string
     */

    private function get_tracks_from_content( $content )
    {
        // Get tracs:
    $content = strip_tags( nl2br( do_shortcode( $content ) ) );

        // Replace last comma:
        if( FALSE !== ( $pos = strrpos( $content, ',' ) ) )
        {
            $content = substr_replace( $content, '', $pos, 1 );
        }

        return $content;
    }


    /**
     * Callback for the [_track] shortcode
     */

    public function track_shortcode( $atts = array(), $content = '' ) 
    {    

        $atts = shortcode_atts( 
            array(
                'src'                        => '',
                'type'                       => ( 'video' === $this->type ) ? 'video/mp4' : 'audio/mpeg',
                'title'                      => '',
                'caption'                    => '',
                'description'                => '',
                'image_src'                  => sprintf( '%s/wp-includes/images/media/%s.png', get_site_url(), $this->type ),
                'image_width'                => '48',
                'image_height'               => '64',
                'thumb_src'                  => sprintf( '%s/wp-includes/images/media/%s.png', get_site_url(), $this->type ),
                'thumb_width'                => '48',
                'thumb_height'               => '64',
                'meta_artist'                => '',
                'meta_album'                 => '',
                'meta_genre'                 => '',
                'meta_length_formatted'      => '',
                'dimensions_original_width'  => '300',
                'dimensions_original_height' => '200',
                'dimensions_resized_width'   => '600',
                'dimensions_resized_height'  => '400',
            ), 
            $atts, 
            'wpse_track_shortcode' 
        );

        //----------
        // Data output:
        //----------
        $data['src']                      = esc_url( $atts['src'] );
        $data['title']                    = sanitize_text_field( $atts['title'] );
        $data['type']                     = sanitize_text_field( $atts['type'] );
        $data['caption']                  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['caption'] );
        $data['description']              = sanitize_text_field( $atts['description'] );
        $data['image']['src']             = esc_url( $atts['image_src'] );
        $data['image']['width']           = intval( $atts['image_width'] );
        $data['image']['height']          = intval( $atts['image_height'] );
        $data['thumb']['src']             = esc_url( $atts['thumb_src'] );
        $data['thumb']['width']           = intval( $atts['thumb_width'] );
        $data['thumb']['height']          = intval( $atts['thumb_height'] );
        $data['meta']['length_formatted'] = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_length_formatted'] );

        // Video related:
        if( 'video' === $this->type ) 
        {
            $data['dimensions']['original']['width']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_original_width'] );
            $data['dimensions']['original']['height'] = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_original_height'] );
            $data['dimensions']['resized']['width']   = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_resized_width'] );
            $data['dimensions']['resized']['height']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['dimensions_resized_height'] );

        // Audio related:
        } else {
            $data['meta']['artist'] = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_artist'] );
            $data['meta']['album']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_album'] );
            $data['meta']['genre']  = sanitize_text_field( $atts['meta_genre'] );
        }

        return json_encode( $data ) . ',';      
    }

} // end class
```